# How to add a jar file path from local maven repo to jenkins properties during runtime

Tags: maven, jenkins, jar

I m trying to add a jar file path to jenkins properties, using the path from maven loaded dependencies in jenkins workspace, any suggestion for the path?

[image]

Comment: Maven usually does not load the dependencies into the workspace.

Comment: Please describe what kind of problem you have ?